# @Async Spring annotation doesn't work

Tags: spring, asynchronous, annotations

I have a method that must create a zip and mat file from the original file uploaded from the user.
So I decided to store only the original file and then, in an async task I would like to create the other two files.
I read that the `@Async` annotation has two limit:
1)Only on public method
2)The `@Async` method must be in a differet object respect the caller class.
So I create a new class and put in it my async method but it still doens't work.
This is the class that calls the async method:

```
@Service
public class FleetAcquisitionServicesImpl implements FleetAcquisitionServices{

    @Autowired
    private DatabaseAcquisitionServices databaseAcquisitionServices;
    @Autowired
    private DatabaseFleetsAndCarsServices databaseFleetsAndCarsServices;

    @Autowired
    private FleetFolderName fleetFolderName; 

    private static final int NUMBER_OF_SHEET=4;
    @Override
    public ArrayList<String> uploadFiles(MultipartFile[] openedFiles, Integer idFleet, Integer idCar, Integer initialKm) throws FileUploadException, FileEmptyException{
        ArrayList<String> filesName=new ArrayList<String>();
        String fileName=null;
        String carPath=null;
        for (MultipartFile openedFile:openedFiles){
            if (!openedFile.isEmpty()) {
                //Copy the file into path specified
                fileName = openedFile.getOriginalFilename();
                try {
                    //Get the path where to store the file
                    Fleet fleet=databaseFleetsAndCarsServices.getFleetById(idFleet);
                    Car car=databaseFleetsAndCarsServices.getCarById(idCar);
                    carPath= fleetFolderName.createCarName(fleet, car);
                    if (FilenameUtils.getExtension(fileName).equals("dat")){
                        fileName = FilenameUtils.removeExtension(fileName)+"_km"+initialKm;
                        //write dat file
                        openedFile.transferTo(new File(carPath +"/"+ fileName+".dat"));                 
                        ZipAndMat.createZipAndMat(carPath,fileName);
                    }else
                        openedFile.transferTo(new File(carPath +"/"+ fileName));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new FileUploadException("you failed to upload " + fileName,e);
                }
                filesName.add(carPath +"/"+ fileName);
            } else {
                throw new FileEmptyException("your file is empty " + openedFile.getOriginalFilename());
            }
        }
        return filesName;
    }

ZipAndMat.createZipAndMat(carPath,fileName)
```

is the async method and it is here:

```
package com.model;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Async;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.AsyncResult;

import com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.MWException;

import dataconversion.Converter;

public class ZipAndMat {


    @Async
    public static Future<String> createZipAndMat(String filePath, String fileName){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(20000L);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        //Open file
        Path path = Paths.get(filePath, fileName + ".dat");
        try {
            //Create zip
            byte[] zip = zipBytes(Files.readAllBytes(path),fileName+".dat");
            Files.write(Paths.get(filePath +"/"+ fileName+".zip"), zip);
            //create mat file
            Converter objConv = new Converter();
            objConv. dat2MatConversion(filePath +"/", fileName + ".dat", 0.2);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return new AsyncResult<String>("Zip not created");
        } catch (MWException e){
            return new AsyncResult<String>("Mat not created");
        }
        return new AsyncResult<String>("Zip created");
    }

    /**
     * Convert a file into zip file keeping the same name
     * @param filename
     * @param input
     * @return
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private static byte[] zipBytes( byte[] input, String filename) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(baos);
        ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(filename);
        entry.setSize(input.length);
        zos.putNextEntry(entry);
        zos.write(input);
        zos.closeEntry();
        zos.close();
        return baos.toByteArray();
    }

}
```

I tried tu but `@EnableAsync` both the caller class and on the confiuration class but it doesn't works.
What is wrong in my code? the static method?
Thanks

Comment: I know nothing specifically about spring, but a quick skim through https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/ shows that you need to call the method on a `@Service` - their examples use a non-static method. Otherwise, you are just invoking `createZipAndMat` as a plain old static method - there is no potential for asynchronicity. Are you sure your 2 requirements are sufficient?

Comment: ZipandMat should be a spring bean ..

Comment: I've tried adding @Component but it doesn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need the following things:

1. `@EnableAsync` on a configuration class to enable async processing in Spring.
2. `@Service` or `@Component` on your `ZipAndMat` class to discover it as a Spring component.
3. Change your `createZipAndMat` method so it's **not static**.
4. Autowire this new Spring component in your `FleetAcquisitionServicesImpl` like this:

   `@Autowired
   private ZipAndMat zipAndMat;`

Then, instead of invoking the static method `ZipAndMat.createZipAndMat(carPath,fileName);` you'll need to invoke it on the autowired spring component instance like this:

```
zipAndMat.createZipAndMat(carPath,fileName);
```

Comment: removing static it works. I didn't  find nothing about static with async annotation. Thank you

Comment: Yes. The kind of magic `@EnableAsync` does usually only applies to spring components. So you need `@Component` or `@Service` and normal instance method to enable Spring to do it's job. It's really worth to read more about what spring does and how, it pays off on the long run.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do below thing to enable async

1.)
@Service
 public class ZipAndMat
...

2.) Caller class should enable async call using @EnableAsync

@EnableAsync
@Service
public class FleetAcquisitionServicesImpl implements FleetAcquisitionServices

Please follow this link for more details
https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/

Comment: I added '@Services' to ZipAndMat, '@EnableAsync' to FleetAcquisitionServicesImpl but I have to still wait that ZipAndMat end.