# Spring @Async method gets executed but is blocking

Tags: java, spring-boot, asynchronous

I enabled async in my configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class ApplicationConfiguration {
    //additional configurations
}
```

I have a test class with an **@Async** test method which takes a few seconds:

```
@Async
    public static void asyncTest() {
        System.out.println("* * * * * * ASYNC TEST 1");
        new BigInteger(9999, 5, new Random());
        System.out.println("* * * * * * ASYNC TEST 2");
    }
```

I call this method when my endpoint is called. The method gets executed, but is blocking everything.
My goal is to immediately respond to the client and execute a long lasting method asynchronously, but I can't get it work even with my test-setup. Thanks for any tip!
Spring 1.5.1 servlet with maven and servlet-api 3.0.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method annotated with `@Async` must not be `static` and it must be placed inside a Spring `@Component` (or @Service, etc).

More details in this question's answers: [@Async Spring annotation doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34898421/async-spring-annotation-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with accepted answer and: after injecting my test class, which contains the the asyncTest method, via @Autowired, the instance was still null. This was because I use a **Servlet** and had to also @Autowire the Servlet.
This helped:
[Autowiring in servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11843690/autowiring-in-servlet)